# LINQ query does not load into data grid

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to load an XML into a DataGridView and correlated the changes from the datagridview to the XML file (CRUD). I've tried various methods, I'm trying to find the best, I've got the XML to load and display correctly and save the changes by iterating through the entire DataGridView and create a new XML document, but that requires a lot of processing. How can I do this in a simpler manner?
I was thinking at loading the XML file into memory within an XDocument and operate the changes from the DataGridView upon that on an Edit_EventHandler so that when I want to save the changes I don't have to parse the entire GridView again. I've tried using LINQ but the query does not load into DataGridView:

```
string path = @"D:\WorkData\users.xml";

xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var q = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("client")
        select new
        {
            Name = item.Element("ID").Value,
            Mail = item.Element("email").Value
        };

dataGridView1.DataSource = q.ToList();
```

and the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<clients>
  <client ID='0000100000' email='email0@mail.com'/>
  <client ID='0000100001' email='email1@mail.com'/> 
</clients>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to access are **Attributes not Elements**. Your query is probably throwing an exception, least its not returning any results that why you don't see anything in your `GridView`. Use the following query to get `Attribute` values.

```
var q = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("client")
        select new
        {
            Name = item.Attribute("ID").Value,
            Mail = item.Attribute("email").Value
        };
```

Comment: I've been so blind! but what about the idea on CRUD operations, is it ok , from your experience?

Comment: @A.K, you already have loaded up the documents in `xmlDoc`,  You can modify your `XDocument` with changes from `GridView` and then later call `xmlDoc.Save` method to create/update your xml file. So your original idea of editing GridView and XDocument in parallel seems good enough.

Comment: I have a problem in making the DataGridView editable, how can I do that?

Comment: @A.K, what kind of application you are targeting, also it is a new question and would be better if you can create a new question with relevant details.

Comment: here is.. something else http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522109/xml-to-datagridview-xsd-verification

Answer (score 1):

Id and email are attributes not elements!

```
var q = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("client")
        select new
        {
            Name = item.Attribute("ID").Value,
            Mail = item.Attribute("email").Value
        };
```